# Is it possible to apply an arbitrary transformation matrix to an image in SPM?

Tags: matlab, matrix, nifti, matlab-spm

I have a somewhat specific task I'd like to do in SPM.

Basically, I have some input NII file `scan.nii` and I would like to apply an arbitrary affine transformation to it, defined by `x y z p r yw`.

`x,y,z,p,r,yw` represent the translations and rotations in each degree of freedom (so say `x=2mm`, `p=0.7deg` and so on). I can get an appropriate matrix with `M=spm_matrix([x y z p r yw])`, but I do not know how I can actually go about applying this matrix to my scan.

Ideally I would want it to output with a new filename or simply as a Matlab variable so I can go and do this many times to the same image, but that is not explicitly necessary.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The matrices are 4x4 and the image slices are 128x128 so I'm not sure how do what you are suggesting.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing (and wrong) comment, see my detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

An affine matrix works on image coordinates, not on the image itself. You need to multiply the affine matrix with the coordinates list of your image, then you will get new coordinates, corresponds to the original coordinates.
In addition, the translation is done by multiplying the 4th column of the affine matrix with additional `1`'s in the last row of your indices list (each match of these, at a single vector-multiplying from that matrix).

So, you need to produce a list of your 3D coordinates, as a 3xn  matrix, then add a row of `1`'s at the bottom, and multiply the 4x4 affine matrix by the 4xn coordinates matrix.

An example, say your image is 4x4x4:

```
[X Y Z]=ndgrid(1:4);
ind=reshape(cat(3,X,Y,Z),[],3)';  % list of all of the indices in the image
ind=[ind; ones(1,size(ind,2))];   % add a row of `1`s
ind_aff=m*ind;
```

The bottom row of `ind_aff` is `1`'s, and you can ignore it. The first 3 rows are now the new coordinates, while each column is coordinates to the value that was coordinated by the same column number in the `ind` matrix.

For example, if

```
m=spm_matrix([3 1 10 0.5 0.9 0.3])
```

You will get this transformation:

```
% old coordinates (column-wise)
ind(1:3,1:3)=

     1     2     3
     1     1     1
     1     1     1

% new coordinates (column-wise)
ind_aff(1:3,1:3)=

    4.5609    5.1547    5.7486
    1.4073    0.7892    0.1711
    9.3693    8.8542    8.3392
```